# what Technologies an ETL Developer can learn?

Tags: business-intelligence

I am working as an ETL developer.
I am thinking to learn something new which is related to my experience.

I am not sure about which one to choose.

please suggest me which technology would be good to learn for my future like bigdata,R,Python etc.

Comment: This is not a study advice site. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related question. The [help] has more information explaining the types of question that are (and are not) proper to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you learn R and python as they are pretty common technologies used in data applications, and when you are comfortable  with them, move to apache spark for big data applications,spark use both R and python , as well as scala which can be another technology you can learn.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple tools, SAP Data Services , informatica, pentaho data integration, etc. Maybe you should evaluate which of them is the one in your organization.